# Does Blender have mechanism for saving and toggling mesh states?

Tags: mesh, workflow

I'm aware of keyshapes, keyframes and armature poses library, but it's not the same thing. The closest I can think of is having multiple vertex groups of the same mesh, but in different time only one should represent current modeling state and other ones should be hidden. The reason for need of this is ability to revert changes after saving project, similar to what I can do disabling modifiers.

Comment: according to your text it sounds like shape keys is what you want. Why can't you take that?

Comment: @Chris Shapekeys force you to have same vertex count for every state.

Comment: yeah, you are right

Comment: Yes, but it is probably not what you want: objects are containers that can contain different meshes, so you can duplicate meshes, stash them away, and then toggle which mesh an object contains.  Otherwise, no.

Comment: @MartyFouts I keep feeling blender should have that feature... There was one time I needed to animate o box opening and I tried using shape keys, but when I used _Y_ to separate on key 1, it separated the objects on the Base key too and totally destroyed the bevel operation on the mesh.

Comment: @MartyFouts Actually, this may work. Only that I will need to name every state meaningly and do not to forgot making them used by fictive user so it will not get deleted accidentally. I just thought that this idea could be implemented in a more specific way, but is not too easy to find as the UI has dozens of buttons and submenus.

Comment: Try add-on [KeyMesh](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPvLQH17Y2Q)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Data-blocks

In the Outliner you can select blender file mode. In the meshes you can see all meshes data block.

[image]

You can duplicate it by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

You can switch between mesh data blocks in the Object Data properties:

[image]

Once copied, you should protect them from deleting by adding fake user (shield icon):

[image]

Datablocks that's not assigned to object and not marked by fake user will be deleted on saving-and-open the file.

## Stashes

An outer solution provides by meshmashine - paid add-on. It has "stashes" that provides same functionality, but in more user-friendly way.

Check video description here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iVYteS1Mfkg&ab_channel=MACHIN3